# Converting two list of strings to an object

Tags: c#, json, list

I have the following base json I create this by parsing a excel sheet:

```
{
"Rows": [{
    "RowId": "f7645b3e-a576-4cfe-a136-481d27b708cf",
    "Columns": ["Code", "Barcode", "SalesRep","Price"],
    "Values": ["bk101", "343131231", "Gambardella, Matthew","44.95"],
    "Status": "QUEUED"
}
```

I would like to parse further each row of the mentioned json to another type which holds the list of the items for example:

```
{
  "Articles": [{
    "Id": "f7645b3e-a576-4cfe-a136-481d27b708cf"
    "Code": "bk101",
    "Barcode": "343131231",
    "SalesRep": "Gambardella, Matthew",
    "Price":"44.95"
  }]
}
```

as you can see, the columns and values are paired. 
I know I can use for loop for this conversions going through the list of columns and values but is there another way in which I could do this conversion in an efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about JavaScriptSerializer...

```
    public class Row
    {
        public string RowId { get; set; }
        public List<string> Columns { get; set; }
        public List<string> Values { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootRowObject
    {
        public List<Row> Rows { get; set; }
    }

    public class Article
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public string SalesRep { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
    }

    string ConvertJson(string jsonRow)
    {
        RootRowObject rootRow = new 
               JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootRowObject>(jsonRow);

        List<Article> articles = rootRow.Rows.Select(x => new Article
        {
            Code = x.Values[0],
            Barcode = x.Values[1],
            Id = x.RowId,
            Price = x.Values[3],
            SalesRep = x.Values[2]
        }).ToList();

        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(articles);
    }
```

Comment: This is way better than using for loops indeed. thanks @caner! :]

Comment: glad to help :)